# Send email in Azure Logic App with binary attachment

Tags: email, email-attachments, azure-logic-apps

I am trying to use the "Send an email" on the office365 connector.

I am trying to send an email with a binary attachement. When i receive the email the content appears to be Base64 encoded. In order for my file to work, the content should not the raw binary payload.

How do i avoid the base64 encoding? I tried removing the base64 part: `@{base64(body('binaryStuff'))}` in the code, but that caused my app to fail, with a "BadRequest" message.

How do i send a binary attachement in my logic app?

Answer (score 0):

After letting the function return Base64 string of the mail attachment instead of byte[], the logic app seems to be able to figure out that the contents is encoded.